# Are there any negative side-effects to overriding .gitignored files using git add -f?

Tags: git

I want to commit binaries when i create a tag, those binaries are .gitignored and git-add says "Use -f if you really want to add them." So, i wonder if this would be a safe thing to do or not.
I want to use this to checkout binaries on a target computer. The old "system" is to keep old versions in a subdirectory named by the date that version was compiled on, which is a little annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, it's safe to add ignored files.  Once added they will be tracked, of course.  If you want to stop tracking such a file without deleting it from your working directory, you'll have to `git rm --cached <filename>`.

However!  Think three times before adding binary files to your git repo;  there's a good chance there's something wrong with your workflow, or you're using git in a way that's not intended.  As soon as you start having a lot of binary files in your repository, you'll notice git getting very, very slow.

For your specific application, you might want to take a look at [git annex](https://git-annex.branchable.com).

Another tip:  If you temporarily need to add a binary file to your repository, do so on an orphaned branch (`git checkout -b --orphan <new_branch>`).  That way, once you've removed the binary again, you can run garbage collection and trim the reflog, and the binary file will be *gone* gone.  If you'd simply added it to your normal tree, it'd still be in a referenced commit, and hence sitting as a blob in your .git directory, slowing things down.

Comment: While i agree that adding binaries to a git repo is not so good, those are in sum 1.64MB and only one of them would be changed from one tag to another. Also i only want those to be inside the tags. git annex seems like a neat synch tool, but is not exactly what i need. i should have added that the old system with the old versions needs to stay in use as the person who is actually using this software would otherwise need to learn to use git which he doesnt have time for. these binaries in the repo are mostly just for me so i can put a tag on a commit, add the binaries and comment on the changes

Answer (score 2):

It is safe. The only reason git warns you is because you marked them as ignored, which means that you told git that you do not want them in the tree.

Git is warning you and requiring you to make it clear that you know that you are currently adding files which are on the ignorelist before just adding them.